# Passing NULL Value to Stored Procedure Through C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I have an update class in my MVC Web App to update a field from the front end. This calls an procedure on the database which updates the cell in the table. (Note: This column can accept NULL values)

If I set this in my C# code then it work as it checks to see if a NULL is passed in the front end and replaces it with an empty string (a space could also work):

```
update.Value = dataModel.Value == null ? string.Empty : dataModel.Value;
```

However, when I query the database table, it's not setting NULL value in the cell but just a blank. How can I pass a NULL value into the procedure through the C# code?

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework to update your database?

Comment: I am using Entity Framework.

Comment: Then just set _Update.Value = dataModel.Value;_ Let EF handle the null. It knows how to do it

Comment: Receive the error: "Error Details:System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Procedure or function 'InsertDataValue' expects parameter '@Value', which was not supplied."

Answer (score 6):

You can use `DBNull.Value` to pass Null value in database. This is .Net substitue of `null` value of DB.

So your code becomes

```
update.Value = dataModel.Value == null ? DBNull.Value : dataModel.Value;
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If I use this, I receive the error: "Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.DBNull' and 'string'"

Comment: In that case use `if else` rather than `ternary operator`.

Comment: I coded: if (dataModel.Value == null) { update.Value = DBNull.Value } else { update.Value = dataModel.Value; }. However, receiving error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DBNull' to 'string'" now. Similar error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", DBNull.Value);`